# The role of finite precision arithmetic in the precision of numerical methods

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

Every book on numerical methods studies the precision of the algorithms as if they will be executed on a machine with infinite precision. Apparently, the effects of using floating point arithmetic (with finite representation) are not very important since they are neglected in the textbooks. However, I guess that these effects must have been studied somewhere. Could you please provide me with a reference?

Updated. Changed the wording of the question as suggested by NoChance.

Comment: While rounding can surely cause problems, I think that more serious issue is to do with number representation in the computer and the use of Floating point arithmetic which maybe more serious.

Comment: I asked this question to my Numerical Methods prof as well. He told me that this is a topic, that for usual the mathematicians shift to the IT guys, and the IT guys shift to the mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

Numerical recipes by Press, Teukolsky and two others does do the analysis including the effects of machine-epsilon rounding.

Comment: In the book authors:
argue that truncation error (error of the mathematical algorithm) and the error of rounding (machine's finite representation error) *typically* do not interact. Also they raise the topic of stability in the algorithms. However, in my experience, stability analysis covers imprecision only of the part of the problem's inputs (e.g. stability w.r.t to y in the problem solve Ax=y  for x).

Comment: Could you  hint us to a point in the text book? I don't see it giving extraordinary effort to the error analysis due to machine precision arithmetic

Comment: It is discussed in The Receipts (3rd edition) at least on the page 11 . However, there is not much said indeed.

Answer (score 0):

*Real Computing Made Real: Preventing Errors in Scientific and Engineering Calculations* by Forman S. Acton includes a lot of practical advice about preserving significant figures in calculations.

However, I don't think there is much in Acton about formal error analysis in the sense of propagation of errors.  For that, you might consider *Rounding Errors in Algebraic Processes* by J.H. Wilkinson.

Comment: I have checked "Real Computing Made Real". While it indeed includes some relevant advice, but definitely does not provide a general framework.

The second book seems to be outdated and could be used as starting point for writing a modern book on the topic. However, it is not something which can be used out of the box for the analysis of applied problems.